# Filtering visualization in Kibana by latest date

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I’m working with ELK version 6.2.3.
I was able to create several visualizations for my data, but I would like for some of them to have a “complex” filter. My index contains an id field and a date field along with other data on which I’m aggregating (I’m not aggregating on the id nor the date). 
I would like the visualization to display the latest date per id. 
I may get data from id ‘x’ today, but for id ‘y’ I only received data two days ago.

For instance, I’ve created a pie chart which aggregates on a field named ‘type’, but I would like to display the data within this chart for the latest data per id.
The document looks like this:

```
Document 1:
{
    “id”: “x”,
    “date”: “June 10th 2019, 10:00:29.000”,
    “type”: “TypeA”
}
Document 2:
{
    “id”: “y”,
    “date”: “June 8th 2019, 10:00:29.000”,
    “type”: “TypeA”
}
```

For each id I would like to get the latest date, not just the past 24 hours or so.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: sort by date descending and size 1 should show you latest data